# About the processing at the home button down

Tags: android

I am thinking of a specific process when the home button is pressed.

- Purpose

I want a specific processing by using the following logic when the home button is pressed.
And it does not use the KeyEvent and Broadcastreceiver.

- Problem

Although the following logic will be worked on Android 4.4, but it will be called also at the time of Activity changes. I mean it doesn't satisfy my purpose from Android 4.4.
I would like to call specific processing only at the time of home button down.

---

```
private static final int ANDROID_VERSION_KITKAT = 19;

@Override

protected void onUserLeaveHint() {

    super.onUserLeaveHint();

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) {
        if (recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString().indexOf(getPackageName()) > -1){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= ANDROID_VERSION_KITKAT){
                if (i == 0){
                    // Processing of Android 4.4
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (i == 1) {
                    // Processing before Android 4.4
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use this 0n activity onPause()...

Comment: Thank you for replying.

I solved the issue by our team member.
He suggest to create the processing that is task management(Activity management) for working on our application.